# What OWIN Middleware Redirects After User Grants Client?

Tags: authentication, oauth, owin

I've looked hard into this article about OAuth Authorization Server with OWIN/Katana: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

The article does tell us how to set up a basic Auth server but seems to omit a lot of information and code. I'm particularly interested in the implicit grant flow. They did provide the login page and the "permissions" page, but I'm confused:

1. Where is the code that decides whether the authenticated user has granted the client? This can't be done "behind the scenes" because we NEVER told any middleware "component" the path "/OAuth/Authorize".
2. Where is the code that actually redirects the user back to the client's website, along with the auto-generated access_token and other values?
3. I'm suspecting that there is a proper way to "construct" the ClaimsIdentity object (particularly the scope claims) before passing it to `authentication.SignIn(claimsIdentity)` in /OAuth/Authorize, so that it would automatically redirect the user back to the client with access and refresh tokens.
4. The MVC Actions of /OAuth/Authorize and /Accounts/Login seem to always return View() even after successful authentication and granting, thus never forwards the user back to the client's website. This seems like I would have to manually determine when to `return Redirect(Request.QueryString["RedirectUrl"]);`, and figure out the encrypted values to pass along with it. This doesn't seem like I should be generating the exact response.

What did I overlook?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? I'm presenting a reference that contains code and how to do something properly, which will require programming on my part!

Comment: Just driving by, but straight from the close reasons:  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  You're asking for book and website recommendations *on top of* the four questions you have.  It could either be "too broad" or "asking for recommendations".  Not a good fit for SO.

Comment: OK. So I'll take that off, and hopefully it'd be considered legit.

Answer (score 0):

As @(LittleBobby Tables) said your questions are very broad.

Based on how you asked the question you actual understand the topics but not the how?

I suggest you look at the full source code at

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-OAuth-20-Authorization-ba2b8783/file/114932/1/AuthorizationServer.zip

Your answers are either present or will lead you in the right direction